# In MS Outlook, report all sent-messages that haven't received replies

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2007

I send out a lot of emails each day and often fail to keep track of which ones actually get replied to.

Is there a way I can use a VBA script to look at say all the sent messages in the last week, and check if they received replies?

Specifically, a report of the sent email messages that have NOT yet received replies to them from at least one of the addresses they were sent to.

I know a little bit of Excel VBA but I don't know where to start with this one... or if it's even possible.

Ideas?

[Asking for a friend, personally I despise Outlook]

Comment: Could you tell us what version of (the despised) Outlook your friend is using? MS has a tendency to make features come and go - no point in helping you figure out a solution for the "wrong" platform. Mac or PC? Outlook 2010? 2012? 2003???

Comment: MS Outlook 2007, on Windows 7

Comment: Ohhhhh 2007....that's like the stickiest of all versions...

Comment: Hi OP, I would like to help, but how One can identify an email is "a reply to a sent mail". Can We assume something like the Subject of the reply email is in the form of "Re: _____" or do we use the sender,recipient to identify this?

Comment: I have a feeling relying on the Subject line "Re: ..." might come with false positives (emails with Re: that are not replies from this inbox) and false negatives (emails that *are* genuine replies, but for whatever reason someone modified the subject line to remove the Re:) to the tracking.

So I'd prefer to use other methods than just relying on Subject "Re: ..." . BUT that would be a partial solution by the sounds of it.

Comment: done some searching online, seems to me there's no field in outlook message indicating the mail is a "replied" mail. So I think you can use 3 things together to identify the mail is a "replied" mail. 
1. the recipient
2. the subject 3. Add a unique signature to out-mail, and check if it's there in the reply.  This will be FALSE Negative.. but a partial solution as you mentioned.

Comment: Part of the standard defining email headers is the "In-Reply-To" header, which contains the Message-ID of the email that was replied to - any email that is a reply should contain this (though it's usually hidden from the user). This is how, for example, mail clients are able to show you a "threaded" view of conversations. I don't know the first thing about Outlook VBA, but I'd start by looking to see if you can access the headers and match messages with their replies by Message-ID and In-Reply-To.

Comment: Thanks @Jez good point! Sounds like this should definitely be implementable

Comment: I have tested the method @Jez mentioned. Tried looking at the Internet header on both side, the "In-Reply-To" and "Message-Id" field are using. Facing 2 difficulties. 1. **UNABLE** to get "Message-Id" in "Sent Item" folder in outlook 2007 client ( NOT Exchange) 2. Not sure if all mail server follows this standard.

Comment: for 1. An easy around is using `BCC` Field to get the `Message-Id` of the `Sent-item`. Reference for Auto-BCC: http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=72

Comment: for 1: I'm **ABLE** to get "Message-Id" in "Sent Item" folder using the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556829/how-to-get-message-id-or-header-in-sent-items-folder-in-outlook-2007-in-vba/14568240#14568240

Answer (score 0):

i know you can track whether it was read / received. follow this tutorial, or a different for your outlook version

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/get-delivery-and-read-receipt-confirmations-HP010080428.aspx#BM1