# How to get Message-Id or Header in "Sent Items" Folder in Outlook-2007 in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

This is a sub-question of this [main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418643/in-ms-outlook-report-all-sent-messages-that-havent-received-replies) question

I am able to loop get the internet header of other folders using the following functions

```
Sub testing()
Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim folder As MAPIFolder
 Dim item As MailItem
Set ns = Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

 For Each item In folder.Items

    If (item.Class = olMail) Then
        GetInetHeaders item
    End If
Next item

End Sub

Function GetInetHeaders(olkMsg As MailItem) As String

    ' Purpose: Returns the internet headers of a message.'

    ' Written: 4/28/2009'

    ' Author:  BlueDevilFan'

    ' Outlook: 2007'

    Const PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"

    Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor

   Set olkPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor

    GetInetHeaders = olkPA.GetProperty(PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID)

    Debug.Print olkMsg.Subject
    Debug.Print GetInetHeaders


    Set olkPA = Nothing

End Function
```

But Not working on the "Sent Items" folder, any one have experience or reference for this?

**FAIL**   the Property returns nothing

```
Sub testing2()
Dim item As MailItem
Set Store = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders
  For Each StoreFolder In Store

      For i = 1 To StoreFolder.Folders.Count
        If StoreFolder.Folders(i).Name = "Sent Items" Then
            For Each item In StoreFolder.Folders(i).Items
                If (item.Class = olMail) Then
                    GetInetHeaders item
                End If
            Next item
            Exit For
        End If
      Next
    Exit For

  Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT** If it's not achievable, I can BCC myself in the email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS is only available on the messages received from a POP3 account. It is never set on the outgoing messages.
Also, there is absolutely no reason to loop through all folders  - use Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail) - it will work even if the "Sent Items" folder name is localized.
Secondly, do you really need to process **all** items in the folder?

Check if the PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID (DASL name schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F) property is set.

Comment: thanks for all the advice,, I try to get the message-id of mail in the "Sent Mail" folder

Comment: Check if the PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID (DASL name http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F) property is set.

Comment: Thanks, using PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID works out perfectly!

May I ask one more question on how you figure out the DASL names/address?

Comment: If you know the property tag number (for a fixed property) or the GUID/id (for a named property), you can construct the string easily. Otherwise you can see it in OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - click IMessage button, select the property, look at the DASL edit box on the right hand side of the IMessage window.